# custom CardView with recyclerview

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, cardview

[image]

hey, I stuck in one problem. I want to make this screen where I want to use edit option(which is shown in image) and custom logo(which in middle of each `cardview`). how can I use all these things? I am in the learning phase. please give some solution.

Comment: Please add some code or images to better explain your question

Comment: Show us what did you try so far.

Comment: Before asking question do some research, try to google correctly. for now what you are looking for here is the best example https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

Comment: @Sarvesh Welcome to SO! Its good that you are at the correct portal. But rather than putting up your requirement, pls research and come back with your initial trials. Then probably you will get help . Happy coding dear!

Answer (score 0):

Extend `RecyclerView.Adapter` to make your own adapter, then extend `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` to make your own view holder. For the ViewHolder, create your own custom layout xml (one of the list-items in your picture). There are several good tutorials on doing this.

Also, to get the grid-look on your RecyclerView, simply use a `GridLayoutManager`.

Here's a link to a tutorial that I found. https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Good luck!